# File Paths error, I can access the image but is not displaying the image on the screen

Tags: html, file, syntax, path

all works just fine till i use (../) twice. any ideeas why is not working? thank you?

i was sopose to go ap 2 folders and go in Birthday Invite Project folder , and acces the rabit picture

1.0 folder
1.1 folder
1.2folder
1.3 folder
2.2folder
2.1 folder
2.2 image

basicly tring to acess a image inside 2.1 folder  when working from 1.3 folder
my sintax beeing :
../../2.1folder/2.2image
and that is not working.
i am working i VS code

i have tried the website. and is not displaying the picture. but when i go trough the file path i can access the picture in the folder 2.1 just fine.

Comment: well... the indentation is gone now . for the folder example. Wtf